# Do this background drawable in android

Tags: android, view, shapes

I need to do this background for a `TextView` (Horizontal line crossing view but without overlap text) in android, I think I should do it with a shape but I don't have idea how.

Anyone has a good approach to it?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"></View>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vieaw"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"></View>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vieaaw"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"></View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="12 ABCDFE GHI" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Do you think could be done without add more views?Just setting a drawable as background for textview?

Comment: its done and shown above . Dont you think its simple

Comment: I wanted to do it with a shape or maybe a layer list, not add a new views..As i request in my question.